# Internet Explorer 9 and below, setting the scrollbar to the right when using a rtl direction on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

The title pretty much explains it.

I need some way to keep using `body { direction: rtl; }` but prevent IE from moving the scrollbar to the left side and keep it on the right. Just like all other browsers. (This is not such a big issue with IE < 9, but IE9 has several bugs when using rtl.)
Anybody got a hack/fix? Thanks.

(Don't mind doing this with jQuery or something...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put everything in a div with dir=rtl, and leave the body alone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is no, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the browser toolbar with a custom bar, using a javascript lib like [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). 
Anyway, I think this is a bad idea and you should live with this feature of IE ;)